# Enregistrer dans un fichier annexe dans une classe perso, à l'aide de \AtBeginDocument et \AtEndDocument

Tags: macros, environments, document-classes, article, auxiliary-files

Bonjour,

Je cherche à mettre en place une classe me permettant de taper un document à la fois prof (complet) et élèves (avec des trous) qui se différencie à l'aide d'un booléen *ifprof*. Mes macro et mes documents fonctionnent bien : il suffit que je mette `\proftrue` ou `\proffalse` en début de document et le tour est joué. Seulement j'aimerais que ces deux documents soient dans un seul pdf l'un à la suite de l'autre à la fin de la compilation via *pdflatex*.

J'ai donc imaginé prendre le contenu complet de mon document .tex, l'enregistrer dans un fichier annexe `\jobname.cpy` et l'appeler deux fois avec `\input{\jobname.cpy}` précédé à chaque fois par `\proftrue` ou `\proffalse`.

J'ai donc testé l'enregistrement du contenu dans un fichier avec le paquet `newfile.sty` et l'environnement `writeverbatim` et voici mon fichier minimum :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \newoutputstream{contenu}
    \openoutputfile{\jobname.cpy}{contenu}

    \begin{writeverbatim}{contenu}
        \lipsum[1-2]
        \today
    \end{writeverbatim}

    \closeoutputstream{contenu}

    \input{\jobname.cpy} \newpage
    \input{\jobname.cpy}

    \end{document}
```

J'ai donc compilé avec pdflatex et ça fonctionne bien ! mon document contient bien deux fois le *lorem* et la date, et le fichier `test2.cpy` contient juste ce qui se trouve dans l'environement *writeverbatim*

J'ai ainsi voulu faire une classe `classetes.cls` qui me permettait donc de ne plus m'occuper de ces lignes de code pour enregistrer dans un fichier et répéter deux fois mon code, grâce à `\AtBeginDocument` et `\AtEndDocument` :

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} %version de latex utilisée
\ProvidesClass{classetest}[28/06/2020 Classe lycée,V1.0] %Nom de la classe sans le .cls

\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{newfile}

\AtBeginDocument{%

    \newoutputstream{contenu}
    \openoutputfile{\jobname.cpy}{contenu}
    \begin{writeverbatim}{contenu}
    }

\AtEndDocument{%

    \end{writeverbatim}
    \closeoutputstream{contenu}

    \input{\jobname.cpy} \newpage
    \input{\jobname.cpy}

    }
```

Et j'ai créé le fichier suivant :

```
\documentclass{classetest}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\today

\end{document}
```

Mais à la compilation :
**! File ended while scanning use of \next. I suspect you have forgotten a `}'...**
et mon fichier est2.cpy' contient : (tout le *blabla* du début est sur une seule ligne)

```
\lipsum[1-2]
\today

\end{document}
```

Je ne vois pas mon erreur, je ne sais pas si ce que je veux faire est impossible, si vous avez une solution autre à m'apporter... j'ai cherché mais je n'ai pas trouvé, et je suis un simple *cuisinier* et ne suis pas assez *sorcier* pour m'engager dans des `\expandafter`, des `\relax` ou autre `\edef`. Par contre je veux bien les utiliser ;)

Merci d'avoir lu jusque là.

Sam

Comment: Remove the `\end{document}` line in est2.cpy. It cannot appear twice. Btw, are people forgetting the fact TeX.SE is in English?

Comment: I'm not sure the code is too happy with those indented lines you have in the first MWE presented. Often verbatim envs will directly look for say `\end{verbatim}` but with no spaces in front. So all those spaces might be what is causing the code to fail;